# Recursive content projection

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I want to make a simple tree component where each node is displayed as the template I set. Something like

```
<my-tree [item]="rootItem">
    item: <b>{{item.name}}</b>
</my-tree>
```

so I could use the same component to display a tree with different markup, like

```
<my-tree [item]="rootItem">
    <div class="beautiful"> item: <i>{{item.name}}</i></div>
</my-tree>
```

I've made a plunker to illustrate https://plnkr.co/edit/LL8T5a1oSWUzOVEy14jv?p=preview
The tree is displaying almost right but without item names. No idea why. Can someone explain please what I did wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like I figured out how to do this (see the plunker link in the question) with the help of [angular2-tree-component](https://github.com/500tech/angular2-tree-component)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want:

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/jEvvEritC99PWkYhRvMj?p=preview)

I just added `{{it.name}}` to

```
<li *ngFor="let it of item.children">{{it.name}}
```

Comment: No. You added it to the tree component itself, but I want all markup to be done in the template that is passed to it - `**<b>{{item.name}}</b>`.  
Tree component do not know what structure in `item` and how to display it, just that it has `children` field.

Comment: I don't think what you want is going to work. You have to add something to the components view directly. If you only have templates withing templates, there is nothing to display for the component.